# MySQL (5.6.14) Syntax error with Declare and Temporary Table inside Procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have following SQL-procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Stuff()
LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_temp AS (
      SELECT id FROM users);
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Which gives an error: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0; END' at line 8"

Now, if I remove the Temporary Table, it runs fine.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Stuff()
LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also if I have some other statement other than the Declare in the Procedure it runs fine.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Stuff()
LANGUAGE SQL
  BEGIN
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_temp AS (
      SELECT id FROM users);
    SELECT * FROM users;
  END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

What might be causing this syntax error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/declare.html):

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Move it before `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE Do_Stuff()
LANGUAGE SQL
BEGIN
   DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_temp AS (
      SELECT id FROM users);
   -- DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```